# SVG filter not working when imbedded with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have been trying to get the blur effect to work when creating the elements and imbedding them with JavaScript. I cannot figure out why the blur will not show up. I have two fiddles, one with the standard HTML & CSS and the other using JavaScript. If anyone wants to check them out and offer an explanation as to what I am doing wrong I would really appreciate it.

HTML & CSS Version (Works)
https://jsfiddle.net/aaronbalthaser/xampLtnr/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/250/sports/" width="300" height="250" />
  <svg width="300" height="60" viewbox="0 0 300 60">
    <defs>
      <filter id="blur">
        <fegaussianblur in="SourceGraphic" stddeviation="5" />
      </filter>
    </defs>
    <image filter="url(#blur)" xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/300/250/sports/" x="0" y="-190" height="250px" width="300px" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

JavaScript Version (Doesn't Work)
https://jsfiddle.net/aaronbalthaser/Lbnkfn02/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/250/sports/" width="300" height="250" />


</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
var width = 300;
var height = 250;
var viewbox = "0 0 300 60";
var namespace = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
var path = 'http://lorempixel.com/300/250/sports/';
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var body = document.body;

var svg = document.createElementNS(namespace,'svg');
svg.setAttribute('width', width);
svg.setAttribute('height', 60);
svg.setAttribute('viewBox', viewbox);

var defs = document.createElementNS(namespace, 'defs');
var filter = document.createElementNS(namespace, 'filter');
filter.setAttribute('id', 'blur');

var feGaussianBlur = document.createElementNS(namespace, 'feGaussianBlur');
feGaussianBlur.setAttribute('in', 'SourceGraphic');
feGaussianBlur.setAttribute('stdDeviation', '5');

var image = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'image');
image.setAttribute('filter', 'url(#blur)');
image.setAttribute('xlink:href', path);
image.setAttribute('x', + '0');
image.setAttribute('y', + '-190');
image.setAttribute('height', height + 'px');
image.setAttribute('width', width + 'px');

filter.appendChild(feGaussianBlur);
defs.appendChild(filter);
svg.appendChild(defs);
svg.appendChild(image);
container.appendChild(svg);

console.log(container);
```

Comment: stddeviation should be "stdDeviation" , fegaussianblur should be feGaussianBlur. SVG is XML - and is case sensitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
image.setAttribute('xlink:href', path);
```

should be

```
image.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", 'xlink:href', path);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lbnkfn02/2/

Comment: I have a question while we're on the topic. Do you know how the extend the blur so the edges of the footer are also blurred. Currently the edges are crisp. I tried some things with negative margins but was unable to make it look good.

Comment: t the moment your SVg is the same size (well width at least) as your image.  If you want to see your blurred edges, you'll want to make the SVG larger.